# Azure media Services to generate gif from a video

Tags: video, gif, azure-media-services

How can we use Azure media services to generate a gif from a mov video.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The video encoder that Azure Media Services uses only outputs MP4 videos as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/encode-media-encoder-standard-formats-reference.  To convert videos to a GIF you would need a different tool.

Comment: In addition to @David's solution - We also support generating a JPEG Sprite thumbnail and corresponding WebVTT file to use with it.   That is handy for doing simple Javascript and CSS animations using the sprite image.  Lots of samples of doing that out there.  

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/VideoEncoding/Encoding_Sprite_Thumbnail/index.ts